# Is it possible to make a villager incapable of reusing or adding trades?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using the `Offers:{Recipes:...` tag, you're able to `/summon` a villager with custom trades, and limits on those trades.

Problem is, once you start trading with that villager, he starts adding new trades, or reopening trades that previously ran out. Is there any way to prevent this?

That is to say, if my villager has exactly one trade with one use, for instance, can I prevent him from opening new, non-custom trades - or worse, reopening the custom one that *should* have had just one use?

I'd prefer to keep him around once his trades run out, and simply be unable to trade with him, but if it comes to `/kill`ing all villagers that don't have active trades, so be it.

Comment: For the limiting new trades being added, you could always add an impossible trade at the end, for example, have a player trade nothing for a barrier. The solution below is honestly much better.

Comment: @David The trades appear even if the others haven't run out yet.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one.

Comment: @pppery Where did I ask a second question?

Comment: "How to prevent a villager from adding new trades" and "How to prevent a villager from refreshing its old trades" are two distinct questions with separate answers and should not have been combined into one question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent new villager trades from spawning?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178230/how-do-i-prevent-new-villager-trades-from-spawning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New trades unlocking can be prevented by setting the `CareerLevel` of the villager to a high number (like 100).

Limiting the trade to `X` times without it being able to "refesh" (refreshing will also increase the maxUses) is done by setting the "maxUses" to its maximum value and "uses" to `X` below.

An example:

> /summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Career:1,CareerLevel:100,Offers:{Recipes:[{uses:2147483645,maxUses:2147483647,buy:{id:stone,Count:1},sell:{id:stone,Count:1}},{uses:2147483645,maxUses:2147483647,buy:{id:stone,Count:1},sell:{id:stone,Count:1}}]}}

Since `maxUses` is set to its maximum, if a refresh is triggered (which will try to increase the `maxUses`) it will overflow to negatives and lock the trade.In the example, the trade can only be used 2 times (since `uses` is `maxUses`-2).

Comment: 100 is nowhere near high enough. I needed to go all the way to 2^31-1 to get him to stop making trades. He'll still spew purple bubbles *as if* he's making new trades, but double-checking his GUI, he doesn't actually do so. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way the current "vanilla" maximum CareerLevel is higher than 100.

Comment: Hey, I'm just reporting what my experience was. I'm working with vanilla 1.12.

Comment: Well, I'm not able to reproduce it... But it doesn't really matter. Using 2^31-1 is just amazing future proofing either way :P.

Comment: You never know. I might still be playing with this map in 3017 and the mobs aren't functioning properly. :P