# Stop custom villagers from generating new random trades on their own

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So lately I've been working on a minigame map with command blocks and I wanted to create a villager shop. However when I set up some custom trades whenever you traded with him it unlocked new random trades, I don't want this to happen is there a way to prevent this? 
(Btw I know this similar has been asked before however the answers didn't quite help me so I decide to ask it myself :D )

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Why did the answers not help you? What results do you get when you try them?

Comment: Some of them were super outdated and some were kinda irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent new villager trades from spawning?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178230/how-do-i-prevent-new-villager-trades-from-spawning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, let's say you have this command to spawn a villager:

> /summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"dirt",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dirt",Count:2}}]}}

This is a basic command. He will sell 1 dirt for 2 dirt. If you want a villager to not unlocks new trades, you set the `CareerLevel` higher than its maximum.

The command should look like this now:

> /summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:1,**CareerLevel:100**,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"dirt",Count:1},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"dirt",Count:2}}]}}

By setting the `CareerLevel` to 100, and by having `Career` set to a value higher than 0 (where a value of 1 works for all professions), we prevented the villager from unlocking new trades upon trading.