# Prevent Villager from restocking in Vanilla game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to (and, if so, how do you) spawn in a villager which is **incapable of restocking**?

I'm going to make a guided Skyblock-like map, with the villager's trades representing different progression tasks (e.g. get 64 cobblestone); I want to make this in an entirely Vanilla way. I want to disable "grinding" for the rewards, however; they should be finite even if they require renewable resources.

(I actually *do want*, if possible, some custom trades to be gated behind level progression; this would make for an extra degree of freedom in the design; but that's not a hard requirement and is out of primary scope of this question.)

- Can one program it to think that its job block must be a Dragon Egg or Barrier block (which it will never find, thus never claim, thus never restock)?
- Can one create a Nitwit (villager unable to claim a job site) who has been, nevertheless, spawned in with some artificial trading ability?
- If one simply assigns it a job block, which is encased in Barrier at y=0, can a crafty player nevertheless convince the villager to abandon it in favor of an accessible one?

Generally: is there any way to do this without mods?

---

This is related to, **but not a duplicate of**, [“How do I prevent new villager trades from spawning?”](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/178230/64297).

- That question concerns how to prevent villagers from *unlocking new trades* when the villager levels up
- I am asking how to prevent them from *restocking existing trades* when they are exhausted

Comment: I am unable to check at the moment, but couldn't you just block their restock tables?

Comment: @MatthewWells That was my idea #3, but as stated in the question I'm unsure whether or not it'd still possible to "coax" it into abandoning its inaccessible job site, leaving it open to claiming one it can restock at

Comment: In 1.15+ The villager without access to his workstation won't restock.

Comment: @SF. #3 was whether it'd be possible for a villager, who's been assigned an inaccessible job site, to somehow be convinced to abandon his inaccessible job site and then be free to claim one that's accessible

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude If the villager has been traded with (any irrelevant stock) he's locked into the current profession and retains current trades and whatever remaining stock he has, until depleted. The villager may be completely deprived of any job site at that point (original destroyed, no replacement) and the effect is he won't be able to restock until he finds and accesses a new, unoccupied work site.

Comment: Although if the player creates a new work site (and in case old exists, it becomes un-pathfindable), the villager will take up the new worksite and restock. The key would be to leave the old worksite, make it pathfindable but not accessible (trapdoors etc) and make it impossible for the player to make it not pathfindable.

Comment: The problem is, the player can easily create a new work site — none of them are made of particularly exotic materials — and I don't see a way to make something "pathfindable but not accessible" *and* "impossible for the player to make it not pathfindable"

Comment: [This sort of setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpLxa.jpg) - with barrier/bedrock instead of glass - would work providing the player doesn't have enderpearls and chorus fruit. The villager is separated from the workstation by a powered iron trapdoor. The player can reach the villager but not the trapdoor. Extra workstation will do nothing. But if the player can enderpearl in, they can destroy the trapdoor and let the villager access the workstation.

Comment: I can also think of a couple other creative ways to break this setup, so it's far from 'decent' (break slab, use trapdoor to enter crawl mode - you'd need some sort of curved corridor instead. With enough redstone skill one could try to pull the trapdoor out using honey blocks or use potion of turtle master to protect the villager then blast the trapdoor with TNT. Generally - it's vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it can be done by adding `{NoAI:1}` tag to the villager, for example this command will summon a cartographer:

`/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:cartographer",type:"minecraft:plains"},NoAI:1b}`

One disadvantage of this method is that the villager will not move at all.

Also, the villager that is summoned that way doesn't need the job site to be placed near it.